# Foreign key pointing to Compound Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I'm working on a POCO entities model on an existing database.
One table has a compound key

```
public class Table1
{
  [Key]
  public virtual int Key1 {get; set;}

  [Key]
  public virtual int Key2 {get; set;}

  public virtual ICollection<Table2> Tables2 {get; set;}

  //more properties here...
}
```

and a second table with no primary key, but 2 properties referencing the compound key of Table1.

```
public class Table2
{
  public virtual int Key1 {get; set;}

  public virtual int Key2 {get; set;}

  [InverseProperty("Tables2")]
  public virtual Table1 Table1 {get; set;}

  //more properties here...
}
```

**QUESTION** Is possible to map this Association using DataAnnotations?
If so, How?

Comment: is for EF an entity with so many attributes is POCO ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can define the compound foreign key with data annotations:

```
public class Table2
{
    [ForeignKey("Table1"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual int Key1 {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("Table1"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public virtual int Key2 {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("Tables2")]
    public virtual Table1 Table1 {get; set;}

   //more properties here...
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
public class Table2
{
    public virtual int Key1 {get; set;}

    public virtual int Key2 {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("Tables2")]
    [ForeignKey("Key1, Key2")]
    public virtual Table1 Table1 {get; set;}

   //more properties here...
}
```

But the real problem is that your `Table2` has no primary key which is required by Entity Framework. I don't think that there is any workaround to solve this problem - other than adding a primary key to the table.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for. Im working with DBAs to get this table a PK.