# EF Relationship Annotation Methods - What are the differences?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

When defining a foreign key relationship using annotations, I see two different ways to accomplish this. Why are there two ways to do this? Is one way more of a standard than the other? Are there any benefits to using one over the other?

The one benefit I can think of is that when using this for composite keys, you will only need one annotation instead of many, if you annotate the related entity.

```
[Table("TEAM")]
public class Team
{
    [Column("TEAM_ID"), Key]
    public int TeamID { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

**Method 1 - Annotating the related Entity**

```
[Table("PLAYER")]
public class Player
{
    [Column("PLAYER_ID"), Key]
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }

    [Column("TEAM_ID")]
    public int TeamID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamID")] //FOREIGN KEY ANNOTATION
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; } //RELATED ENTITY
}
```

**Method 2 - Annotating the foreign key column**

```
[Table("PLAYER")]
public class Player
{
    [Column("PLAYER_ID"), Key]
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Team")]  //FOREIGN KEY ANNOTATION
    [Column("TEAM_ID")]
    public int TeamID { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; } //RELATED ENTITY
}
```

Comment: This post shows an example of the compound foreign key annotations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7987583/4347337

Comment: Which one you use is a matter of personal preference. Either way, you’ll end up with the same foreign key in the database. So, there is no difference between the two variants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no significant difference between the two methods. Both will result in the same class mapping. The only benefit of using one method over the other is in the case of composite keys. For composite keys, it is more readable to use **Method 1 - Annotating the related Entity**, because it only takes one line of annotation instead of many.

If composite keys are not an issue, use whatever convention is standard for the project.

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int A {get;set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int B {get;set;}
    public virtual List<Child> Children {get;set;}
}
```

**Method 1 - Annotating the related Entity**

```
public class Child
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public int B {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("A, B")]
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```

**Method 2 - Annotating the foreign key column**

```
public class Child
{
    [ForeignKey("Parent"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int A {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("Parent"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public int B {get; set;}
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```